# Xamarin forms :Size of an image inside a carousel view

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a carousel view inside a stasklayout which is also inside a scroll view, the carousel view contains an image which is displayed in miniature, I want that the image is displayed in actual size.How to do it please?

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <cv:CarouselView  ItemsSource="{Binding  MediaItems}"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
            <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image  Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Source="{Binding Uri}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </cv:CarouselView>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Label Text="{Binding tappedItem.ShortDesc}"  IsVisible="{Binding ShortText,Mode=OneWay}" FontAttributes="Italic" FontFamily="Sans-serif"  />
        <Label Text="{Binding tappedItem.LongDesc}" IsVisible="{Binding LongText,Mode=OneWay}" FontAttributes="Italic"/>
        <local:BorderlessButton Text="{Binding BtnText}" FontSize="Medium"  TextColor="DodgerBlue" FontAttributes="None" Clicked="Button_Clicked"  />
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: les questions doivent être en anglais

Comment: I have a carousel view inside a stasklayout which is also inside a scroll view, the carousel view contains an image which is displayed in miniature,I want that the image is displayed in actual size.How to do it please?

Comment: Edit your question _and_ title

Comment: You need to include some code, we're not going to write it for you from scratch.

Comment: And images of code are heavily criticised here too I'm afraid.

Comment: include code as text, not as image

Comment: @Patrick I already add the code can you answer me please?

Comment: @maccettura can you answer me please?

Comment: I dont know anything about Xamarin.  I wont be able to help you

Comment: @maccettura No problem thank you any way .

Comment: @DavidG can you answer me please?

Answer (score -1):

See is there any property for caursoel view like HasUnEvenRows property in listview.

Comment: I tried to search about something like this but there is not any property like this .

Comment: This is not an answer... You should use the comments